# SAM AWS - Testing AWS Lambda that depend on layers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-lambda-layers

I am using AWS SAM framework to build a coupled services Lambda and api gateway. 
I am facing some difficulties to run a unit and integration tests for my lambdas functions which 're using layers (utilities functions, models, controllers, config ...)

I can stub some functions, but others are necessaries, a specially some librairies that i want to be on layer (such as lodash, ...).

Thank you in advance for your help.

> Clarification

I have a project which is structured as following

- serverless-poi

  - events/ => contains all events for local tests
  - lambda-create-poi

    - tests/unit/lambda-create-poi-spec
    - index
    - package
  - lambda-delete-poi
  - lambda-update-poi
  - lambda-list-poi
  - lambda-list-poi
  - layer-poi

    - nodejs/

      - package
      - conf
      - models
      - controllers
      - utiles
      - some-shared-lib (ex: lodash, bluebird, ...)

All others lambdas have the same structure as lambda-create-poi.

I am planning to industrialize the deployement via bitbucket-ci. My pipline looks like :

```
image: amazon/lambda-build-node10.x
pipelines:
branches:
master:
- parallel: 
   - step:
        name: lambda-create-poi
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - cd lambda-create-poi
          - npm install
          - npm test

    - step:
        name: Same for other lambdas
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          #- cd lambda-xxxx
          #- npm install
          #- npm test

- step:
   name:  Package  
   script:      
        - pipe: atlassian/aws-sam-deploy:0.2.3
          variables:
             AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
             AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
             AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
             S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
             STACK_NAME: 'my-stack-name'
             SAM_TEMPLATE: 'template.yaml'
             CAPABILITIES: ['CAPABILITY_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND']
             COMMAND: 'package-only'
- step:
    name:  Upload to S3  
    script:
        - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.3.2
          variables:
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
            # template packaged.yml after pipe atlassian/aws-sam-deploy package-only execution
            LOCAL_PATH: '.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/aws-sam-deploy'
            EXTRA_ARGS: '--exclude=* --include=packaged.yml'

- step:
    name: Deploy stack  
    script:
        - pipe: atlassian/aws-sam-deploy:0.2.3
          variables:
           AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
           AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
           AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
           S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
           STACK_NAME: 'my-stack-name'
           TEMPLATE: 'https://bucket-access-lambda.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/packaged.yml'  
           CAPABILITIES: ['CAPABILITY_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND']
           WAIT: 'true'
           WAIT_INTERVAL: 60
           COMMAND: 'deploy-only'
```

My problem is in the parallel step can not find the layer for the unit testing. All the units tests failds (I have to stub all the layer event the utiles I use)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add more details about the difficulties you are facing?  The more specific you can be, the more likely it will be that others can help you and give direct solutions.

Comment: Hi Shawn, 
I completed my question by posting an answer. I couldn't find a way to update my question.

Comment: There should be a faint gray link under the tags in your question to "edit" it

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?